# parallel execution of CUDA kernels

Tags: c, cuda

Consider following pseudo-code, where a and b are GPU arrays. Three Cuda kernel calls are made.

```
square<<<N,M>>>(a, length);
cube<<<N,M>>>(b,length);
add<<<N,M>>>(a,b,length);
```

1. square each number of a
2. cube each number of b
3. add corresponding elements of a and b

Is it possible that before square and cube kernels are finished, add kernel gets executed and it reads older values of a and b?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible that before square and cube kernels are finished, add kernel gets executed and it reads older values of a and b?

Not as you have written it.  In CUDA, activity flows in streams.  Streams are ordered paths of execution.  Basic stream semantics say that for 2 items issued into a stream (i.e. *both* issued into the *same* stream), those items will execute in issue order.  Item 2, issued after item 1, will not begin execution until item 1 has completed execution.  CUDA streams enforce this.

Another characteristic of streams is that even if you don't explicitly identify a stream, you are using the NULL (or default) stream, for all stream-able activity, which includes anything that can take a stream parameter.  [Your kernel launches can take a stream parameter](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#execution-configuration).  Since you have omitted this:

```
square<<<N,M>>>(a, length);
            ^
            no stream parameter
```

you are using the NULL stream (for all 3 of your launches) and CUDA stream semantics dictate that those kernels will be serialized.

[This](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) entire doc section will be useful reading to understand concurrency, and you can get an idea of some of the requirements to witness kernel concurrency by studying the CUDA concurrentKernels sample code.